# Which vehicle has this "van with smiling face" icon?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I saw this icon today and was confused:

[image]

Searching for "GTA vehicle with custom icon" brought me to [this page](https://www.gtabase.com/grand-theft-auto-v/guides/list-of-vehicles-in-gta-5-gta-online-by-feature?feature=icon-unique), which unfortunately did not cover this specific icon that I saw.

What car is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [**Brickade 6x6**](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Brickade_6x6) or an **[Acid Lab](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Acid_Lab)**, which is a modified Brickade 6x6. The Acid Lab is a mobile business introduced in the [Los Santos Drug Wars update](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/GTA_Online:_Los_Santos_Drug_Wars) (Dec. 2022). You run the Acid Lab with the [Fooliganz](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Fooliganz), a faction that has the smiley as one of their symbols.
[image: Brickade 6x6 / Acid Lab HUD icon]

To get your own Acid Lab, you need to complete the [First Dose](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/First_Dose) missions and then the [Setup: Acid Lab Equipment](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Setup:_Acid_Lab_Equipment) mission. The alternative (more expensive) method is to buy it from Warstock Cache & Carry for GTA $1,450,000.